# forbid access from outside to static resources of asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an asp.net application which is has a URL say "mysite.com" and I have a subdomain "static.mysite.com" Which hosts static resources (images, css and js files).

I want those resources accessible only from "mysite.com" and "static.mysite.com". I mean other person should not be able to refrence my resource from his/her web site.

How Is it possible ?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

if you have access to your server IIS, the easiest way is to set a filter in IIS for unknown requests. but as you are using asp.net MVC and maybe .net 4 or later(?) (it's possible to request for static files in .net 4 and later) you can achieve by enabling CORS in asp.net MVC:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.EnableCors();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                 "DefaultName",
                 "{controller}/{id}",
                new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

EnableCORS provides you to cross origin for all kinds of request, for example:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://www.Domain.com", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

so, if you want to forbid all unknown accesses to your resources, you can deny all request by defining the origins:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class MyCorsPolicyAttribute : Attribute, ICorsPolicyProvider 
{
    private CorsPolicy _policy;

    public MyCorsPolicyAttribute()
    {
        // Create a CORS policy.
        _policy = new CorsPolicy
        {
            AllowAnyMethod = true,
            AllowAnyHeader = true
        };

        // Add allowed origins.
        _policy.Origins.Add("http://subdomain.domain.com");
        _policy.Origins.Add("http://www.domain.com");
    }

    public Task<CorsPolicy> GetCorsPolicyAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(_policy);
    }
}
```

see the article, as I used it when I wanted to do solve the problem:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: Thanks Ehsanm but I just want to deny to static resources, is it possible with your code?

Comment: you can test it, try to make the "build action" of your files as "Embedded Resources". in that case requests within your application only will be able to access them.